# Migrate application from Wildfly 8.1 to Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: wildfly, cdi

When deploying my application (perfectly running on Wildly 8.1) to Wildfly 10.1.0 i get the following error:

```
15:01:34,829 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool --   
   83) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app-admin: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app-admin: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.enterprise.application.web.listeners.UserListener
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.enterprise.application.web.listeners.UserListener
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
... 6 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.enterprise.application.web.listeners.UserListener
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedListener.start(ManagedListener.java:50)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.start(ApplicationListeners.java:159)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:175)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry$ComponentManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ComponentRegistry.java:149)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$6.createInstance(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1379)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedListener.start(ManagedListener.java:48)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke private void com.enterprise.application.web.listeners.UserListener.initTransactionContent() on com.enterprise.application.web.listeners.UserListener@638ad521
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:100)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:81)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:126)
at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor$3.run(WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor.java:195)
at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor$AbstractInjectionTargetDelegatingInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldComponentIntegrationProcessor.java:259)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:107)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:98)
... 49 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:689)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:90)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
at org.jboss.weldx.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest$1568423357$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getSession(Unknown Source)
at com.enterprise.application.web.listeners.UserListener.initTransactionContent(UserListener.java:43)
... 54 more
```

I think that I have problems with CDI because the error occur in a @PostConstruct method of class UserListener where CDI injected HttpServletRequest (with @Inject) is used.

Some more details of application:

- BOM version used 8.1.0.Final (tried also with 9.0.0.Beta2)

Comment: Can you share the code of `UserListener`?

Comment: Problem is with RequestScope context not active. Do you use any Spring Framework parts ? Do you have your beans.xml modified ? Any extensions used ?

Comment: The CDI 1.2 spec defines when is the `RequestScope` active in section 6.7.1. I *guess* that your `UserListener` is a Servlet `HttpSessionListener`. If so, and if I am reading the spec right, the request scope is not supposed to be active!